# Capture all mysql queries

Tags: networking, mysql

I want to capture all the queries on one of the mysql server without enabling general query logs (because that leads to high IOPs) by using tcpdump or ngrep, and then i want to pipe those queries over netcat to port 3306 of the mysql instance running on different machine and run them there. Is this possible since all the authentication with username and password also has to take place in the destination machine.

Comment: Sounds like you want to trade an IO problem for a memory/processor problem.

Comment: Setup the [mysql-proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/)  It permits you to setup a filter to log statements.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671777/how-to-trace-mysql-queries-using-mysql-proxy

Answer (score 2):

Cole's script may accomplish what you are trying to do, but it really sounds like you are trying to manually accomplish [statement-based replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-formats.html) -- I'd suggest it would be easier and perform much better to simply use the built-in replication to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Found this script [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/18/how-to-use-tcpdump-on-very-busy-hosts/) that should do what you're looking for. However as it has been said, you could end up with performance issues with memory/cpu using this method.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Set some defaults
    d=$(date +%F-%T | tr :- _)
    self=`basename $0`
    REMOTEHOST='some.other.hostname'           # CHANGEME
    LIMIT=50  # limit # of queries in report
    SLEEPTIME=1200  # duration to capture tcpdump data in seconds (1200 = 20 min)
    TMP='/tmp'
    LOCKFILE="$self.lockfile"
    TMPfile="$self.temp"
    RESfile="$self.result"
    # check lock file
    if [ -e "$TMP/$LOCKFILE" ]; then
     echo "$self: lock file $LOCKFILE already exists, aborting"
     exit 1
    fi
    # set trap to be sure tcpdump doesn't run for ever
    # and clean up the temp file too
    trapÂ  'rm -f $LOCKFILE; kill $PID; ssh $REMOTEHOST -- "rm -f $TMP/$TMPfile"; exit' INT TERM EXIT
    touch $TMP/$LOCKFILE
    # run the tcpdump & write to remote file and sleep for a bit
    tcpdump -i eth0 -s 65535 -x -n -q -tttt 'port 3306 and tcp[1] & 7 == 2 and tcp[3] & 7 == 2' 2>/dev/null \
     | ssh $REMOTEHOST -- "cat - > $TMP/$TMPfile" &
    PID=$!
    sleep $SLEEPTIME
    kill $PID
    # set trap to be sure both remote files are removed
    trap 'ssh $REMOTEHOST -- "rm -f $TMP/$TMPfile $TMP/$RESfile"; rm -f $LOCKFILE $RESfile; exit' INT TERM EXIT
    # digest the result, copy to localhost, then email it
    ssh $REMOTEHOST -- "mk-query-digest --type tcpdump --limit $LIMIT < $TMP/$TMPfile 2>&1 > $TMP/$RESfile"
    scp -q $REMOTEHOST:$TMP/$RESfile $RESfile
    # email $RESfile using your preferred transport
    # clean up remote and local files.
    ssh $REMOTEHOST -- "rm -f $TMP/$TMPfile $TMP/$RESfile"
    rm -f $RESfile $LOCKFILE
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
    exit 0
```

Comment: There are some weird characters in there.